# ajax calls on mvc takes a lot of time

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance, partial-views

I have a simple MVC page, 1 page, making 3 ajax GET calls to fill 3 div's on the main page.
when the call happens i noticed it took seconds sometimes before the partial views were loaded over ajax in the div's.
So you could clearly see the divs being updated each one after the other...

When i created a project from scratch with the same setup it was less severe, but i got similar behavior.

The strange thing is, i tried making 3 ajax call's to the came controller method, and this is working a lot faster than when i change it to call the real controller method...

[Initial start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXFKQ.png)

[First request with all same partial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwopd.png)

[Second request with all different partial results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6bnp.png)

The Razor code for the main page is

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row mb-3">
    <input type="date" id="gameDate" name="gameDate" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                First Container
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="scientisttimes" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Second Container
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="criminaltimes" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Third Container
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="tlhtimes"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Ajax call javascript is

```
@section scripts{
<script>
    $("#gameDate").change(function () {
        var date = $("#gameDate").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("FirstTime", "Book")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#scientisttimes").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#scientisttimes').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SecondTime", "Book")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#criminaltimes").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#criminaltimes').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ThirdTime", "Book")',
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#tlhtimes").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#tlhtimes').html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

each partial view is similar with different text, so very very basic

```
<div>
    First
</div>
```

The controller code is also very simple als follows

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult FirstTime()
    {
        return PartialView("_FirstPartial");
    }

    public PartialViewResult SecondTime()
    {
        return PartialView("_SecondPartial");
    }

    public PartialViewResult ThirdTime()
    {
        return PartialView("_ThirdPartial");
    }
```

So when i change the javascript to call 3 times the same partial view instead of 3 different ones. I just get extreme long times (over a second...) this is not workable. Check the links for details on the timings

does anyone have any idea on what i am overlooking, or where this behavior is coming from?

grts,
Lander

Comment: Look at server status while making the requests, slowness seems to be on server side.

Comment: It is indeed on the serverside. but i don't know where to start looking. since these are the only server side functions i am calling.

Comment: Check server logs for errors, check cpu/memory usage, just to start.